# Globally store all command line / bash / windows terminal input and output into text log files

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, terminal

I am looking for a global and automated way to always log all the input and output of all of the command line windows I am using into text files.

I am using 3 types of console on Win 10 - git-bash.exe, cmd.exe and wt.exe, so I am looking for a solutions for all of them (obviously separate solutions).

It would need to log into files with a timestamp per day or per session or whatever - as long as its automated and stored in plain text.

Comment: for cmd, this answer (or one of the other ones): https://serverfault.com/a/1049766/411612 . Powershell is probably easiest to add `Start-Transcript` to your ps profile, or enable windows powershell auditing at system level. Those would work for any 'terminal'